# How to get "tag name", "attribute name", "attribute value" in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that needs to return every tag name, attribute name, and attribute value

Here is the code example

```
Hello, My name is Jack, This is my selfie:
[img id='4' src="imageurl"]
Below is the quick-link to my profile
[profile username='jackisbest']
```

I need to get any text enclosed in [ ]

Also I need javascript regex to parse them and match them this way

```
> Match 1: img

> Match 2: id='4'
  Group 1: id
  Group 2: 4

> Match 3: src="imageurl"
  Group 1: src
  Group 2: imageurl
```

This is the regex I am using, but it can only match attributes and value

```
(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What about `\[([a-zA-Z]+)|(\S+)=(["'])(.*?)\3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\[([a-zA-Z]\w*)|([^=\s]+)=["'](.*?)["']/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mOn3n/1). *Details*:

- `\[([a-zA-Z]\w*)` - a `[` char and then a letter followed with zero or more word chars (letters, digits, underscores)
- `|` or
- `([^=\s]+)` - one or more chars other than `=` and whitespace
- `=` - a `=` char
- `["'](.*?)["']` - `"` or `'`, then any zero or more chars as few as possible (captured into Group 3), and then a `"` or `'` char.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your regex to catch the tag name and used named capture groups.

`/\[?(?<tagName>\w+)\s?(?<attName>\S+)=['"]?(?<attValue>(?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']/gm`

This might work for you.

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/kT7pG4/1

Comment: I found that the label name will be repeated, this is not good for me
but I have solved the problem, the regex is as follows
`\[([a-zA-Z]+)|(\S+)=["'](.* ?)["']`
[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/oTV6TJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the opening `[` and the closing `]` into account and the quantifier in the l[ookbehind is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can use:

```
(?<=\[(\w+\b)[^\][\n]*)([^\s=]+)=['"]([^'"]*)['"](?=[^\][\n]*])
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `(\w+\b)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word characters
  - `[^\][\n]*` Optionally match any char except `[` `]` or a newline
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `([^\s=]+)=['"]([^'"]*)['"]` Capture **group 2** and **group 3** for the key and value
- `(?=[^\][\n]*])` Assert a `]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qiztlb/1)

The pattern has in group 1 the value of the value right after the opening `[` and group 2 and group 3 are the values of the key and value pairs:

```js
const regex = /(?<=\[(\w+\b)[^\][\n]*)([^\s=]+)=['"]([^'"]*)['"](?=[^\][\n]*])/g;
const str = `Hello, My name is Jack, This is my selfie:
[img id='4' src="imageurl"]
Below is the quick-link to my profile
[profile username='jackisbest' a='b']`;
let m;

console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2], m[3]]));
```